# Is there a way to return a JSON object within a xe:restViewColumn?

Tags: rest, xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

I'm trying to generate a REST-Service on a XPage with the viewJsonService service type.

Within a column I need to have a JSON object and tried to solve that with this code:

```
<xe:restViewColumn name="surveyResponse">
 <xe:this.value>
<![CDATA[#{javascript:
var arrParticipants = new Array();

arrParticipants.push({"participant": "A", "selection": ["a1"]});
arrParticipants.push({"participant": "B", "selection": ["b1", "b2"]});

return (arrParticipants);
}
]]>

 </xe:this.value>
</xe:restViewColumn>
```

I was expecting to get this for that specific column:

```
...
"surveyResponse": [
      { "participant": "A",
        "selection": [ "a1" ]
      },
      { "participant": "B",
        "selection": [ "b1", "b2" ]
      }
    ]
...
```

What I am getting is this:

```
...
"surveyResponse": [
      "???",
      "???"
    ]
...
```

When trying to use toJson for the array arrParticipants the result is not valid JSON format:

```
...
"surveyResponse": "[{\"selection\": [\"a1\"],\"participant\":\"A\"},{\"selection\": [\"b1\",\"b2\"],\"participant\":\"B\"}]"
...
```

When tyring to use fromJson for the array arrParticipants the result is:

```
{
   "code": 500,
   "text": "Internal Error",
   "message": "Error while executing JavaScript computed expression",
   "type": "text",
   "data": "com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx: Error while executing JavaScript computed expression at com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptValueBinding.getValue(JavaScriptValueBinding.java:132) at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.rest.DominoViewColumn.getValue(DominoViewColumn.java:93) at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.rest.DominoViewColumn.evaluate(DominoViewColumn.java:133) at com.ibm.domino.services.content.JsonViewEntryCollectionContent.writeColumns(JsonViewEntryCollectionContent.java:213) at com.ibm.domino.services.content.JsonViewEntryCollectionContent.writeEntryAsJson(JsonViewEntryCollectionContent.java:191) at com.ibm.domino.services.content.JsonViewEntryCollectionContent.writeViewEntryCollection(JsonViewEntryCollectionContent.java:170) at com.ibm.domino.services.rest.das.view.RestViewJsonService.renderServiceJSONGet(RestViewJsonService.java:394) at com.ibm.domino.services.rest.das.view.RestViewJsonService.renderService(RestViewJsonService.java:112) at com.ibm.domino.services.HttpServiceEngine.processRequest(HttpServiceEngine.java:167) at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.rest.UIBaseRestService._processAjaxRequest(UIBaseRestService.java:242) at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.rest.UIBaseRestService.processAjaxRequest(UIBaseRestService.java:219) at com.ibm.xsp.util.AjaxUtilEx.renderAjaxPartialLifecycle(AjaxUtilEx.java:206) at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.renderAjaxPartial(FacesServletEx.java:225) at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:170) at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160) at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138) at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103) at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576) at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1281) at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:847) at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796) at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565) at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1265) at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:653) at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:476) at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:341) at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:297) at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272) Caused by: com.ibm.jscript.InterpretException: Script interpreter error, line=7, col=8: Error while converting from a JSON string at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSGlobalObject$GlobalMethod.call(FBSGlobalObject.java:785) at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161) at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSGlobalObject$GlobalMethod.call(FBSGlobalObject.java:219) at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:175) at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTReturn.interpret(ASTReturn.java:49) at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpret(ASTProgram.java:119) at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpretEx(ASTProgram.java:139) at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression._interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:435) at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.access$1(JSExpression.java:424) at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression$2.run(JSExpression.java:414) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:284) at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:410) at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:251) at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:234) at com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:221) at com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:193) at com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptValueBinding.getValue(JavaScriptValueBinding.java:78) ... 27 more Caused by: com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonException: Error when parsing JSON string at com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonParser.fromJson(JsonParser.java:61) at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSGlobalObject$GlobalMethod.call(FBSGlobalObject.java:781) ... 43 more Caused by: com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.parser.ParseException: Encountered " "object "" at line 1, column 2. Was expecting one of: "false" ... "null" ... "true" ... ... ... ... "{" ... "[" ... "]" ... "," ... at com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.parser.Json.generateParseException(Json.java:568) at com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.parser.Json.jj_consume_token(Json.java:503) at com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.parser.Json.arrayLiteral(Json.java:316) at com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.parser.Json.parseJson(Json.java:387) at com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonParser.fromJson(JsonParser.java:59) ... 44 more "
}
```

Is there any way to get the desired answer?

Comment: you've gott error 500, so look into IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT directory, xpages* log, what is exact cause of the error.

Comment: The error is thrown because the method fromJson expects a string (or boolean). But arrParticipants is of type object. Just to mention again. This is not the problem I am struggling with. I want to get a correct (valid) JSON response for the REST service. But the response delivers invalid strings.

Comment: What you are seeing is intentional to stop remote code injection exploits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the best way to achieve the desired result is to use the **xe:customRestService** if you need to return a cascaded JSON object.

All other xe:***RestService elements assume that you will return a flat JSON construct of parameter and value pairs, where the value is a simple data type (like boolean, number or string and - funny though - arrays) but not a complex data type (like objects).

This is, that this result here

```
...
"surveyResponse": [
      { "participant": "A",
        "selection": [ "a1" ]
      },
      { "participant": "B",
        "selection": [ "b1", "b2" ]
      }
    ]
...
```

will be only available on using **xe:customRestService** where you can define your JSON result by yourself.

Using the other services the results are limited to this constructions:

```
...
"surveyResponse": true;
...
```

or

```
...
"surveyResponse": [
      "A",
      "B"
]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

cant you use  built-in server-side javascript function **toJson** ?

Comment: Sorry, the error is thrown when using fromJson. But the result with toJson is also not the result I was expecting (see the edited question).

Answer (score 0):

You could try intercepting the AJAX call when reading the JSON and then manually de-sanitise the JSON string data.

There are more details here.

http://www.browniesblog.com/A55CBC/blog.nsf/dx/15112012082949PMMBRD68.htm

Personally I'd recommend against this as unless you are absolutely sure the end user can't inject code into the JSON data.

Comment: I am trying to expose a REST-Service which can be accessed from another web-site (using a widget or url). There is no AJAX call which can be intercepted. The best way to solve the problem is to use the xe:customRestService.